# How to clear the contents of a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I know there is some questions like this around, but they don't seem to work because they completely remove the view and that's not I want.

I have this design, a dual pane where I have a fragment and a Fragment Layout. Where the details on the right are shown. See image: [image]

The problem is when I switch tabs and come back to Measurement tab, the fragment on the right doesn't clean it self. See image: [image]

The information on the right is added programmatically on run time, some LinearLayout for the Header, another LinearLayout for the details and another LinearLayout for the buttons that are at the end when you scroll the details on the right.

I tried using:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) FindViewById(Resource.Id.data_memory_details).Parent;
vg.RemoveView(FindViewById(Resource.Id.data_memory_details));
```

and:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) FindViewById(Resource.Id.data_memory_details).Parent;
vg.RemoveAllViews()
```

But this doesn't work because it completely removes the right side, the next time it loads the left pane is filling the whole width of the screen.

Another small question would be, where is the correct place to clean the contents? Should I do it OnPause()? When I change tabs and the Measurement Activity goes to the OnPause could I clean there?

Answer (score 1):

do your login in -

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
   //write  your logic here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to android. I don't understand what you just put. Should I make this method on my Master Activity class? Does android execute it when I leave the activity or should I use it inside OnPause, for example?

Comment: if you are using then this is an override method of fragment.just override this method and write your code in it.

Comment: But isn't supposed android to execute the OnDetach? Because I don't know what code to write in it. I just want to clear the content, not the views or write some logic. There is a Clear() method that I can "attach" to the fragment I want?

Comment: you should use onDetach method to clear you view data.Suppose you have a EditText inside your fragment and in onCreate() method you have set value to it like mEditeText.setText("Initial Value").then in detach() method write code like mEditText.setText(""); so when next time fragment is loaded then EditText will not contain previous value.

Comment: So basically on my OnDetach I should clear my contents by "hand"?
And this OnDetach should be on my DetailFragment or MasterFragment class?

Comment: yes you have to write code to clear content and it should be inside your fragment.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to clean the contents of the layout by "hand" and I'll say something back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear data from the fragment,
Go to the activity that contains that fragments and use

```
getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_STACK);
```